# R, getting data.frame factor name by index

Tags: r

I have a data frame, and I'm trying to get name of its factor (as string) by index.

For example,

```
var1=factor(c(0,2,2,6,7),levels=0:7)
var2=factor(c(2,2,0,1,6),levels=0:7)
obs1=data.frame(var1,var2)
obs1[1]
```

returns

```
  var1
1    0
2    2
3    2
4    6
5    7
```

Is there a way to return just "var1"?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `names()` or `colnames()`.

```
names(obs1)[1]
```

Answer (score 2):

Try `names(obs1)[1]`.  This with return the name of the first variable in your `data.frame`.